# How to find and list file name differences in two directories?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have two folders:

```
\txt
\pdf
```

I have batch converted *.txt files from `\txt\*.txt` to `\pdf\*.pdf`.

`\txt` has 6000 files.
`\pdf` has 5950 files.

How can I use a Windows batch file to list the 50 files not in `pdf`, so that I can check why the conversion failed on these 50 files?

In essence: two directories should have files with the same file names, but a different file extension. List the 'missing' file names.

Comment: You can save the "dir" output into a .txt file and then compare using excel or a file comparison software.

Comment: :) Well... there is an efficiency and elegance in a DOS batch file unmatched by other methods... hence, my question as is. I was able to write the batch conversion FOR etc. but did not get to the point of comparing the file names in two different DIRs.

Comment: You can extract txtdir.txt and pdfdir.txt list. Open in excel, delete file extensions and use VLOOKUP function and find which files are missing.

Comment: *an efficiency and elegance in a DOS batch file*? If you did it simply via a text diff utility, you'd have been done faster than you could post the question here. That's *efficient and elegant*.

Comment: Efficient and elegant is to think outside the box.

Comment: batch is nowhere an efficient tool. A specific compiled app do things much faster than an intepreted shell. And this is [**not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: Look at the solution... no application required, no spreadsheet, delete this and that and VLOOKUP, etc. -- I don't think this question was about the validity of DOS batch commands over problem-specific applications :) ... though I do appreciate your input.

Comment: vbs, powershell... all are built into Windows, no external applications needed, and they're much better tools than cmd.exe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for %t in (\txt\*.txt) do if not exist "\pdf\%~nt.pdf" >>missing.txt echo %t
```

(from the prompt)

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! It works... it is elegant, not requiring any other 'helpers' :)

Comment: @Ken, from memory, the redirection can go anywhere in the "command", I often used that to prevent the trailing space caused by `echo something >afile` since I'm anal about separating words and don't want to do `... something>afile` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:Turns out you're both right and I wasn't. :-) Works on Win 10 from a prompt. Will clean up in a minute or two when you've both had a chance to see this..

Comment: `>qq.txt echo hello` followed by `type qq.txt` *definitely* shows it's going into the file. And the redirection belongs to the `echo` rather than the `for` (Iwasn't sure about that aspect but I checked) since, if you change it from `>>` to `>`, only the *last* one ends up in the file.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Yep, that's what I discovered as well. Thanks to both of you for the lesson. :-)